# Can someone help me identify the font in this image?

Tags: font-identification

Thanks for any help in advance. I just need to know the font in this image!

[image: need to know font in this image!]

Comment: Hi Seth, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. We have a collection of font identification resources [right here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info), and it is a good idea to try those first. Please let us know what you have tried without luck. Always good to show a little effort, and chances of getting a good answer increase. Please don't be discouraged, we know that using this site can be a learning curve. We *are* happy to have you!

Comment: thanks for the comment. and i have used various other resources that upload the image and try to identify letters from it to correctly identify the font, to no avail. I will try using the resources you just suggested, however.

Comment: Yes, we are happy to have you... But more than for just one post!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you will like [ED BRUSH](http://www.houseind.com/fonts/edbenguiatfonts) font -

[image]